# SharePoint search on Ranking

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, ranking, sharepoint-search

I have a SharePoint Site in a list there is column called category, while searching accross the site if the search keyword found in Category then the result should come on the top of the search result.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want search Result on top when the search keyword was found in that category column what I need to do??